# Dynamically added options disappear if added multiple times

Tags: jquery

I just came up with a strange glitch. In my opinion, it is a bug. I wanted to hear your thoughts on this.

Shortly I will describe the issue here:

Lets say I need 3 selects with the same options, I create them in HTML like this:

```
  <select id="x1" class="A"></select>
  <select id="x2" class="A"></select>

  <select id="y1" class="B"></select>
```

Then I want to populate them with options using jQuery. I do it like this:

```
var options = [];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
  options.push($("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>"));
}

$(".A").append(options);
$(".B").append(options);
```

There are 2 elements with class `A` and 1 element with class `B` in this example. After calling `$(".A").append(options)`, it does everything as expected - it adds those options to selects with class `A`. But then, after calling `$(".B").append(options)`, it adds those options to elements with class `B`, but options for the last element with class `A` disappear! This seems very strange!

The effect would be the same, if I add them like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
  var option = $("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
  $(".A").append(option);
  $(".B").append(option);
}
```

[JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/puretizewi/1/edit?html,js,output)

I ended up using `$(".A, .B").append(options)` to add those options to all selects, but this does not seem right.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `options` always refers to the same set of DOMElements, so your code is actually adding the options to the first `select`, then immediately transferring them to the other. If you want to duplicate the elements, you need to `clone()` them:

```
$(".A").append(options);
$(".B").append(options.clone());
```

You use of `$(".A, .B").append(options)` is perfectly legitimate and, in my opinion, a better solution.

**[Working Demo](https://jsbin.com/nesaqabeyu/1/edit?html,js)**

Alternatively, you could change the `option` generating logic to create a single string which can then be appended anywhere you require:

```
var options = '';
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     options += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
}

$(".A").append(options);
$(".B").append(options);
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about cloning them. A little hickup was with the fact that those options are in a generic JS array, I would have to loop them again to make clones.

Comment: You're right - I missed that you were creating an array of jQuery object. You could amend this to build a single string instead which would both avoid the issue completely and be quicker. See my update.